# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' - Conda Enviroment

Tags: python

I'm trying to import module torch at jupyter notebook, but the error message appers: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'". But I already installed the package.

When I run the command below, seem to be already installed as well

**!pip install torch==2.0.0

Requirement already satisfied: torch==2.0.0 in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from torch==2.0.0) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->torch==2.0.0) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\br\appdata\local\miniconda3\envs\models\lib\site-packages (from sympy->torch==2.0.0) (1.3.0)**

But when I try to import, the message error:

```
import torch

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 # Imports
----> 2 import torch
      3 import sklearn
      4 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that the `pip` command is linked to some other version of python that is installed on your computer.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the full output of this command `pip --version` and also this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`